# what is none tag image in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I want to know why we have none tag image for every image except the original image?
[image]

```
[root@worker ~]# nerdctl -n k8s.io images
REPOSITORY                    TAG        IMAGE ID        CREATED         PLATFORM       SIZE         BLOB SIZE
calico/cni                    v3.27.0    2d38b2f9a14c    7 days ago      linux/amd64    201.4 MiB    90.3 MiB
calico/cni                    <none>     2d38b2f9a14c    7 days ago      linux/amd64    201.4 MiB    90.3 MiB
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30179716/2072269

Comment: please post text, not a picture of text ... copy and paste text into your question

Comment: @jsotola I pasted the result